# git stash pop retrieved only some changes

Tags: git

I stashed all changes which I could see all with `git stash show` command:

```
valenta@WSKKOS879 MINGW64 /c/Daten/Projekte/nextgen_coolant/HvUnit (feature_184932)
$ git stash show
 Sources/Common/CommonSettings.h                    |   2 +-
 Sources/IARProject/HvUnit.ewp                      | 148 ++++++++++++---------
 .../InterComSignalIf_DiagRequests.c                |   3 +
 Sources/MCAL/Config/Dio_cfg.cfg                    |   8 +-
 Sources/MCAL/Config/Opb_cfg.cfg                    |   2 +
 Sources/Main/main.c                                |  17 +--
 Sources/SimpleRealTimeScheduler/Srts.c             |  22 +--
 Sources/SimpleRealTimeScheduler/Srts.h             |   2 +-
 Sources/SimpleRealTimeScheduler/Srts_Cfg.c         |   2 +-
 Sources/SimpleRealTimeScheduler/Srts_Slots_Cfg.c   |   4 +-
 10 files changed, 110 insertions(+), 100 deletions(-)
```

It then I wanted to retrieve them back with `git stash pop` command:

```
valenta@WSKKOS879 MINGW64 /c/Daten/Projekte/nextgen_coolant/HvUnit (feature_184932)
$ git stash pop
On branch feature_184932
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   Sources/IARProject/HvUnit.ewp
        modified:   Sources/IoHwAb/InterCom/InterComSignalIf/InterComSignalIf_DiagRequests.c
        modified:   Sources/MCAL/Config/Dio_cfg.cfg
        modified:   Sources/MCAL/Config/Opb_cfg.cfg

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .vscode/
        build/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (d9c5f5a5121c5d8e183d0efa7e9533c53420a344)
```

But only some of them were retrieved, why? what can I do now?

Comment: First, keep the id of the dropped stash at hand so you do not lose it, just in case. Now..... I can't think of a reason why this happens _unless_ those changes are already applied on the place where you are standing. Is that the case? If you went back to the same _commit_ you were on when you stashed that _and_ you applied it there (using `git stash apply d9c5f5a5121c5d8e183d0efa7e9533c53420a344`), it should apply all changes.

Comment: @eftshift0 No, I don't have any of those changes already applied. But I stashed it from reverted commit on branch which I then removed. Is this not allowed when working with git stash?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, whatever is changed from index will be saved in the stash object..... the fact that you applied or reverted other things should _not_ make a difference. If you run `git stash show -p d9c5f5a5121c5d8e183d0efa7e9533c53420a344`, does it show_all_ changes you originally meant to stash?

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes.

Comment: try this, _as a experiment_. Go to the commit where you created the stash from, do `git stash apply d9c5f5a5121c5d8e183d0efa7e9533c53420a344; git add .; git commit -m "A test"; git rebase --onto the-commit-or-branch-you-are-working HEAD~`. That will _try_ to carry those changes into the branch that you are working on.... if it carried over all the changes, then run `git reset --soft HEAD~` to get the branch pointer where you were originally. If it did _not_ carry over all changes, you need to find out _why_ (which would be a surprise to me, quite frankly) and at least stash is not a variable.

Comment: @eftshift0 I could see changes with `git status` when I used stash apply, but when I committed, it disappeared and it was not preset in commit.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Show `git status` after applying the stash... add the files, status again, then commit, then status again.

Comment: @eftshift0 I found the problem, my stash changes were not from what it was to what I wanted but from what I wanted to what it was. Not sure how I managed to stash it other way around. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*preamble:*

perhaps you weren't aware of it: `git stash` actually stores changes in git by creating a commit (a regular merge commit). You can have a view of that by running `git log --oneline --graph stash` :

```
$ git log --oneline --graph stash
*   df1c341 (refs/stash) WIP on master: ba7d0ba create a.txt
|\  
| * d9f6a3e index on master: ba7d0ba create a.txt
|/  
* ba7d0ba (HEAD -> master) create a.txt
* ...
```

- the top commit itself holds the content of your worktree (files on disk, including not yet staged changes)
- the "index ..." commit holds the content of the index (the staged files)

As you can see, these commits are based on the active commit at the moment when you run `git stash`.

---

When you run `git stash show`, `git` shows you the differences of your stash commit *when compared to its base commit* (commit `ba7d0ba` in the diagram above).

When you apply a stash, it is applied on your new active commit, which may be different from that base commit. Some changes may already be part of your new `feature_184932` branch for example, and not show up as differences anymore.

`git` mentions the sha of the commit that used to be your head `stash`, you can use that sha to compare its content to your current files on disk :

```
git diff d9c5f5a5121c5d8e183d0efa7e9533c53420a344

# or in a graphical diff viewer:
git difftool -d d9c5f5a5121c5d8e183d0efa7e9533c53420a344
```

You can then evaluate if some changes are missing.

Note that this diff will include content that was committed on your `feature_184932` branch since you ran `git stash`, so viewing the diff requires understanding what is an expected difference and what is a missing piece of code.